# Sqlite - query 1 column in two identical tables where column equals a value

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have two identical tables (month1, month2) and I am trying to find all records from both tables where task1_done = 1.  I want the last row in that set (i move cursor to last for this).  I have played with inner outer natural joins but can't seem to get month2 values. Here is what I have:

String query = "SELECT m1.columnA, m1.columnB, m1.columnC, m1.columnD, m1.columnE, m1.columnF FROM month1 m1, month2 m2  WHERE m1.task1_done = 1 OR m2.task1_done = 1";

Any help would be great!

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM month1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM month2) a WHERE task1_done='1'` should work...? The problem is that the "last" value isn't clear, you're not ordering by anything so which is last?

Comment: I use cursor.moveToLast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these tables related or have any references? if not you can have separate statement and do a union

i.e.

```
select top 1 column1, column2.. from month1 WHERE task1_done = 1 order by IdentityColumn Desc
union 
select top 1 column1, column2.. from month2 WHERE task1_done = 1 order by IdentityColumn Desc
```

Comment: Thank you all for your replies!  I went with a combination of the two of your replies.  I checked the one that more closely resembled my DB band aide.  

String query = "
SELECT m1.columnA, m1.columnB, m1.columnC, m1.columnD, m1.columnE, m1.columnF FROM month1 m1 WHERE m1.task1_done = 1 
   UNION 
SELECT m2.columnA, m2.columnB, m2.columnC, m2.columnD, m2.columnE, m2.columnF FROM month2 m2 WHERE m2.task1_done = 1";

Comment: Gordon is correct.  I would have a simple query if all data was in same table.

Comment: Using my UNION (above) can you UNION more than two tables?  I tried adding month3 in same fashion but it only queries month1 and month2.

Comment: Had to switch to UNION ALL between the three SELECTs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a `union all` for this query:

```
select m.*
from (select *
      from months1
      union all
      select *
      from months2
     ) m
where task1_done = 1;
```

Note:  I have used `*` as a convenience because you said the two tables have the same structure.  You should actually list the columns that you want from the two tables.

In general, having two tables with the same layout is a sign of a bad database design.  It is usually better to have a bigger table, with another column identifying "month1" or "month2".

EDIT:

SQL tables do not have a "last" value.  If you have a an id or timestamp column that you can use for ordering, then you can do:

```
select m.*
from (select *
      from months1
      union all
      select *
      from months2
     ) m
where task1_done = 1
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Than you for the reply.  I agree that identical tables is a bad database design - a column of distinction on a bigger table would be better.  However, I am not able to reconstruct DB at time so a band aide query is all I have.  I will test tonight.